# How to fix "no matching fuction for call to:" error in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, inheritance, constructor

I'm writing a program for salary statements and I get this wierd error when I 
inherit purely virally.

I already checked whether I made some mistake in the baseclass or anywhere else but I can't find one.

Base class:

```
class abrechnung {
public:
    abrechnung(int periode, mitarbeiter& mitarbeiter);
    virtual ~abrechnung();
    int getPeriode();
    mitarbeiter getMitarbeiter();
    virtual double getVerdienst()=0;
    std::string toString();
private:
    int periode;
    mitarbeiter arbeiter;
};
```

Derived class:

```
class gehaltsAbrechnung: public abrechnung {
public:
    gehaltsAbrechnung(int periode, mitarbeiter arbeiter, double gehalt);
    virtual ~gehaltsAbrechnung();
    double getVerdienst();
private:
    double gehalt;
};

gehaltsAbrechnung::gehaltsAbrechnung(int periode, mitarbeiter arbeiter,                                     
double gehalt): periode(periode), arbeiter(arbeiter), gehalt(gehalt) {}
```

The unexpected error messages are:

```
no matching function for call to 'abrechnung::abrechnung()'
class 'gehaltsAbrechnung' does not have any field named 'periode'
class 'gehaltsAbrechnung' does not have any field named 'arbeiter'
```

What did I do wrong and how can I fix that?

Comment: Why do you create *two* obstacles to people reading your code? 1) C++ (can't be helped). 2) German (can be rectified) - the international language of programming is english; like it or not, it's a *fact*. Don't make things harder for everyone by using non-english names.

Answer (score 1):

You should invoke base class constructor instead of trying to initialize base class fields in derived class (which is not allowed):

```
gehaltsAbrechnung::gehaltsAbrechnung(int periode, mitarbeiter arbeiter,
    double gehalt): abrechnung(periode, arbeiter), gehalt(gehalt) {}
```

also `mitarbeiter` should probably be passed as `const &`